# iOS app keeps using same icon on springboard

Tags: ios, xcode

I want to create two apps on my iphone for two different demonstrations of same app.

I build the first demo (project name "1ST DEMO"), and it runs okay.

I then change the project name to "2ND DEMO", change the behavior to 2nd demo, and build it.

But instead of two icons on springboard, it still shows the "1ST DEMO" icon, but which now runs the 2nd demo behavior.

How can I achieve two springboard icons:  "1ST DEMO" and "2ND DEMO" ?

Comment: As @dmorrow has answered, first app will be overwritten if the same Bundle Identifier is used for the second app. you will need to create two separate bundle identifiers if you want two different apps at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

You must also change the app Bundle Identifier as well